# How do I delete existing id's from Android App?

Tags: android

In my app that I am making I deleted the textview and editviews and I had given them all new id's but when I went to redo what I deleted I wasn't able to because I have existing id's and I don't know how to delete them so I can reuse the id's. Whereabouts would I do this?

Comment: you can not delete ids remove view or component it will be automatically

Comment: I did remove the view but when I add another and use the same id I keep getting an error that the id already exists.

Comment: it always gives warning not error rebuild by cleaning it wont show error

Answer (score 1):

Ids get created and deleted automatically when you build the project. Sometimes this does not work 100% right away, just clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Hi, I tried the clean and rebuild but it gives the same error when I give an editview the same id from the editview that I deleted prior.

Comment: Oops never mind, its working. Thanks for answering though. I just restarted Eclipse and it was fine again.